# Replacing a value (int64) in series of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried the code below to change 'new_col's value from 3 to 1.
First of all, the random matrix was generated with an index of ['a','b'] and column name [x1~x5]
I then additionally added 'new_col'.

I needed to call the row through column 'x1', therefore I ran`df[df['x1']==val]`, then I thought I could simply convert 'new_col's value by running `df[df['x1']==val]['new_col'] = 1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size = (2,5)), index = ['a','b'], columns = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'])

df['new_col'] = [3,1]

val = df['x1'].iloc[0]

df[df['x1']==val]['new_col'] = 1
display(df)
```

However, it doesn't change anything with an error

```
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests? (i.e., using `loc` instead)

Comment: @fakedad Yes, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but this could be a solution:

```
df["new_col"] = np.where(df["x1"]==val,1,df["new_col"])
```

so for each position, where the rows in x1 columns == val, return 1; otherwise return the value of new_col

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is close to solution but the syntax need a little bit changed to avoid the warning.

You can use `.loc` with the boolean index for filtering as the first parameter and the column name as second parameter , as follows:

```
df.loc[df['new_col']==3, 'new_col'] = 1
```

Demo

```
print(df)

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  new_col
a   3   7   9   8   8        3
b   4   5   9   0   7        1

df.loc[df['new_col']==3, 'new_col'] = 1

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  new_col
a   3   7   9   8   8        1
b   4   5   9   0   7        1
```

### Edit

As per updated requirement from comment:

> What I really need to do is, first find the rows where 'x1' ==4 (in
> your solution), then change its new_col in that row accordingly. –

we can use:

```
df.loc[df['x1']==4, 'new_col'] = 1
```

Comment: What I really need to do is, first find the rows where 'x1' ==4 (in your solution), then change its new_col in that row accordingly.

Comment: @BrianLee  Brian, see my edit for solution updated for your updated requirement.